# Bottom app bar icon display blurred

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am working on UWP app and I have issue regarding the bottom app bar icon which is not displayed properly.

I used a PNG format image with the size of 48*48 dimension, but the icons are not properly visible in bottom app bar. I attached a screenshot of the bottom app bar.

Screenshot:

[image]

This is my code, can anyone suggest me how to get proper icon for the bottom app bar.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar x:Name="applicationbar"  Background="#FFE45427"  IsSticky="True" PointerEntered="applicationbar_PointerEntered" PointerExited="applicationbar_PointerExisted" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="bottombar" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                <AppBarButton Label="HOME" x:Name="appbarhome"    Click="appbarhome_Click" PointerEntered="btnFilter_PointerEntered" PointerExited="btnFilter_PointerExited" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Dashboard" ToolTipService.Placement="Top">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/product-default-small.png"  />
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>

                <AppBarButton Label="Sales" x:Name="appbarsales"   Click="appbarsales_Click" PointerEntered="btnFilter_PointerEntered" PointerExited="btnFilter_PointerExited" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Sales" ToolTipService.Placement="Top">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_sales.png"/>
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>


                <AppBarButton Label="POS" x:Name="appbarpos"   Click="appbarpos_Click" PointerEntered="btnFilter_PointerEntered" PointerExited="btnFilter_PointerExited" ToolTipService.ToolTip="POS" ToolTipService.Placement="Top">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_pos.png"/>
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>


                <AppBarButton Label="Customer" x:Name="appbarcustomer"  Click="customer_Click" PointerEntered="btnFilter_PointerEntered" PointerExited="btnFilter_PointerExited" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Customer" ToolTipService.Placement="Top">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_customers.png"/>
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>

                <AppBarButton Label="About US" x:Name="appbarAboutUs"  Click="aboutus_click" PointerEntered="btnFilter_PointerEntered" PointerExited="btnFilter_PointerExited" ToolTipService.ToolTip="About us" ToolTipService.Placement="Top">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_aboutus.png"/>
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>

</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the topic of [generating icon image](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madenwal/2015/11/24/generating-your-tileicon-image-assets-for-windows-10-uwp-using-photoshop-actions/)

> These 7 templates/actions essentially output 68 of the required and recommended images assets for all the scale sizes (100, 125, 150, 200, 400) and package images needed to ensure your application looks great on any screen!

So, you need to create and resize your icons for other screen resolutions and apply correct name:

```
menu_aboutus.Scale-100.png
menu_aboutus.Scale-125.png
menu_aboutus.Scale-150.png
menu_aboutus.Scale-200.png
menu_aboutus.Scale-400.png
```

OS automatically selects the correct icon